# How can I lock Docky?

Tags: 11.10, xfce, docky, lock

I set up Ubuntu with Docky and Xfce for my mother. But sometimes she accidentially removes Apps from Docky by letting them "drop" on the desktop.

Is there a way to lock docky, so the programs can't be removed that easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Docky provides a [Kiosk Mode](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Kiosk_Mode):

> Docky would be a wonderful addition to an interactive kiosk environment, allowing you to have a beautiful interface to launch the apps your kiosk provides.
>
> In this environment you generally want a read only interface. To achieve this in Docky, you will have to set several GConf values:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/ShowSettings false
> gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/ShowQuit false
> gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/FileApplicationProvider/AllowPinToDock false
> gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockDragTracker/ProvidersAcceptDrops false
> gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockDragTracker/LockDrags true
> ```
>
> Since the Docky icon now does nothing when left clicked, you will also want to either set:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/ShowDockyItem false
> ```
>
> which entirely hides the Docky icon or set a new action for clicking the Docky icon:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/DockyItemCommand "/some/command"
> ```
>
> Once these are set, restart Docky. Docky will now disallow dragging (or removing) icons from the dock, have no way to add items to the dock and have no way of accessing the settings dialog!
>
> Please note that some docklets might expose their own settings dialogs/configuration via their popup menus (GMail, Weather, NPR, Clock, etc). Also some docklets will let you modify the system state (NetworkManager, Session, etc). You might want to think hard about each docklet you add to a kiosk environment!